# SQL*Plus in Shell Script: Send COUNT(*) to Variable, Error to File

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix

I'm calling Oracle SQL*Plus from the Korn shell (ksh).

My ultimate goal is to get the value from a SQL statement's `COUNT(*)` into a shell-script variable.

However, if a SQL error is raised, I would like to report the SQL exception in full and terminate the script.

I'm having a hard time accounting for both scenarios to my satisfaction.

```
#!/bin/ksh

test_count=$(sqlplus -s scott/tiger << EOF1
    WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1
    SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM scott.emp WHERE empno > 7777;
    EXIT;
EOF1
)

sql_ret_code=$?

if [ $sql_ret_code -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Error encountered."
    echo
    exit 1
fi

echo "test_count = $test_count"

exit 0
```

In the "happy path" case, the above works (in that it displays `test_count = 8`).

If I simulate a SQL error by referencing a nonexistent table (e.g., "`scott.emp_bogus`"), the code above prints only the generic message "Error encountered."  I would prefer to report the full Oracle exception, something like this:

```
Error encountered.

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM scott.emp_bogus WHERE empno > 7777
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I have been playing around with redirecting my `stderr` to a file, to "`cat`" out in case of an exception, but then my non-error-condition output was *also* being directed to that file, which I don't want.

In the absence of any SQL error like this, I would simply prefer to direct the value of `COUNT(*)` to the shell-script variable `test_count`.

If, on the other hand, the SQL raises an exception, I would prefer to direct that error to a file, and then `cat` that file from within my "Error encountered" condition/`if` clause.

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something, but you have everything here to make it work!

### Except you leave the script too soon (with `exit 1`):

You must not exit in error case, because the error you want do display is in your result variable **`test_count`**! so why not displaying it too?  Here is what I can propose

```
[...]
if [ $sql_ret_code -ne 0 ]
then
  echo "Error encountered."
  echo
  echo "ERROR: $test_count"
  echo "abort."
  exit 1
fi

echo "test_count = $test_count"

exit 0
```

(hope I'm not blatantly out of the game ;)